# Why container moves to right?

Tags: html, css

Why container moves to right ? any ideas ? I tried everything, thanks for help and it doesnt move only when image isnt that big.
     .header-container {
    height: 153px;}

```
 .header-container .header {
height: 90px;
min-width: 1000px;
background: #f2743a;
border-top: 63px solid #ffffff;}

  .header-container .header .header-inside {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;}
.header-container .header .header-inside .logo {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: -60px;}
.header-container .header .header-inside .header-nav {
float: right;}
.header-container .header .header-inside .header-nav ul {
padding: 31px 0px 31px 20px;}
.header-container .header .header-inside .header-nav ul li {
display: inline-block;}
.header-container .header .header-inside .header-nav ul li a {
padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;}
 .header-container .header .header-inside .header-nav ul li a:hover {
background: #85be64;
border-radius: 3px;}
```

HTML

```
   <div class="header-container clear">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-inside">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/88MTH3i.jpg"></img></a>
            <div class="header-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Namai</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontaktai</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="main-container clear">
    fdghfghfdghg
</div>
```

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8utdR/)

Answer (score 0):

change min-width to header-container header

example :

```
.header-container .header {
   width: 400px;
}
```